# Is it possible to redirect a page with new url after executing template in Go?

Tags: go

The problem I'm having is pretty much the same as [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53694748/execute-template-submit-issue-due-to-no-http-redirect), but the answer there doesn't really give me a clear idea of how to solve it.

I want to send data to a new page after a user submits a form, so you naturally use `ExecuteTemplate` from `html/template` package.

This redirects a page to the new page with data, but the url stays the same.

This means that if you submitted a form on `http://example.com/login` using `ExecuteTemplate`, you go to a new page with data, but its url still shows `http://example.com/login`.

I tried placing `http.Redirect(w, r, "/newPage", http.StatusSeeOther)` just after the `ExecuteTemplate` code, but the result was the same, which means that the page moved to the new page with data, but the url stayed `http://example.com/login` instead of getting `http://example.com/newPage`. Is there a solution to this?

I'm using Go version 1.13.3.

Comment: why would you execute a html template and then redirect to a new page?
that seems very illogical to me

Comment: Agreed. I also thought it was illogical, but I was trying to make this work somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never have to display a template in a redirect response. It also doesn't make any sense.

There are 2 ways to achieve the effect you want.

### With Redirection

This is your original workflow. You should think of this form page `http://example.com/login` in 3 steps:

1. User open the login page. And you display the normal login form.
2. User submit the login form. You receive a submission from the login form, so you will redirect user to the page **with flag and data**.
3. User is redirected. You found out that you need to display a form / page with data, you display something other than the form.

But how do you determine that you've reached (3)? One way is to append data to the URL on redirection. Let's say we read the GET parameter for a "step=2":

```golang
func loginPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  if r.URL.Query().Get("step") == "2" {
    // show the form / page described in (3) above.
    // ...
    return
  }

  // suppose your form method is POST
  if r.Method == "POST" {
    if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
      // handle parse error
    }

    // handle form submission normally
    // also somehow store the form submitted value for later use
    // ...
    // ...

    // now redirect to the url, as described in (2)
    http.Redirect(w, r, "/login?step=2")
    return
  }

  // handle the normal form display as described in (1)
  // do your ExecuteTemplate
}
```

### Without Redirection

Alternatively, you can also do this without any redirection. Just think of this in 2 steps:

1. User open the login page. And you display the normal login form.
2. User submit the login form. You found out that you need to display a form / page with data, you display something other than the form. No redirection

```golang
func loginPage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  // suppose your form method is POST
  if r.Method == "POST" {
    if err := r.ParseForm(); err != nil {
      // handle parse error
    }

    // handle form submission normally
    // also somehow store the form submitted value for later use
    // ...
    // ...

    // handle the special form / page display as described in (2)
    // do your ExecuteTemplate
    // ...
    // ...

    return
  }

  // handle the normal form display as described in (1)
  // do your ExecuteTemplate
}
```

Comment: `One way is to append data to the URL on redirection.` Thanks, that makes sense. I made this whole application based on templates so I feel like I need to change a lot or like you said I won't do the redirection whatsoever. Anyway, your answer gave me an insight of how I'm going to handle this moving forward. Thank you.